# PHP static variables and objects as a singleton

Tags: php, zend-framework

I was a Java engineer for some time and now some circumstances ask mi to develop PHP code.

Shortly, I was trying to keep a static object inside a class, but any function call results in null.

```
static private $instances;

static public function getSingltoneInstances() {
    if (self::$instances == NULL) {
        self::$instances = Alarmstatistics_Model_AlarmStatistics::getReportInstances();
    }
    return self::$instances;
}
```

I feel static means something different in PHP?

Comment: Nope, its the same.  Your issue is likely within `::getReportInstances()`.

Comment: if you get null, then getReportInstances is returning null. plus, "Singltone"? Singleton, perhaps?

Comment: http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html - Singleton - take note of the warning `You should be wary when using the singleton pattern, as by its very nature it introduces global state into your application, reducing testability.`

Comment: what if the function is called from 2 different http requests ?

Comment: @MarcB, saying results in null, I mean always the execution enters inside ih block and reinitialized, the instance is taken whenever 2 sequential HTTP request is made, I tried already some 100 different ways, still every call to getSingltoneInstances() reinitialize's the static array.

Comment: Nothing persists in PHP applications - the whole PHP application will load up from scratch on each HTTP request (this is how PHP works). So the first call to your `getSingltoneInstances()` method *in each request* will always run your report instances function. If you're from a Java background then that might be what's confusing you.

Comment: Thanks @TimFountain, that is what I am stumbled upon, I mean why else we need static variables if they are getting destroyed every time. So now because of that, I have to query the information from database, that puts a lot of load on SQL server, do you have in your mind any workaround, to keep the data on a session level?

Comment: If the function call is expensive you can cache the resulting data *outside* of PHP (e.g. memcache, file system etc.). Take a look at the Zend_Cache component.

Comment: stuff it into $_SESSION, then. that's the go-to method for persisting php data between individual requests. there's fancier things, but sessions are available out of the box.